# Removing empty DDLs from Main Menu using Panels

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net

I have a main menu in which each menu category drops down. It reads the drop down data from a database and there are times when a particular menu option will contain nothing when it is dropped down. I therefore wish to remove that menu option if the drop down list is empty. Here is my code..

```
<li><a style="color:#fff";">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" style="font-weight: bold; color:#fff;background:#444444; border:0;  text-indent: 5%; text-align-last:center; z-index:-1;" class="fixDDLCategorySize" Height="29px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged"  >
    </asp:DropDownList></a>
</li>

<li><a style="color:#fff";">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" style="font-weight: bold; color:#fff;background:#444444; border:0;  text-indent: 5%; text-align-last:center; z-index:-1;" class="fixDDLCategorySize" Height="29px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl2_SelectedIndexChanged"  >
    </asp:DropDownList></a>
</li>
...ETC
```

In VB, when a menu option is empty I try ddl1.visible=false but it still leaves a block on the screen which the css is causing. I therefore tried this..

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server" Visible="true">
    <li><a style="color:#fff";">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" style="font-weight: bold; color:#fff;background:#444444; border:0;  text-indent: 5%; text-align-last:center; z-index:-1;" class="fixDDLCategorySize" Height="29px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged"  >
        </asp:DropDownList></a>
    </li>
</asp:Panel>
```

and then used pnl1.visible=false to remove an empty menu category but all the other menu options then lose all their css.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm guesssing it's the css in the stylesheet which applies changes to the way the <li> looks. So without altering that, I'm hoping there's a way round it here.

Comment: Don't think you should have a drop down list inside an anchor - not valid html